# wrong time and resolution axis when plotting time series (secs instead of min)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to plot a DataFrame as a time series

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df['time'],df['Power'])
```

or

```
df2 = df.set_index('time')
df2.Power.plot()
```

which both show all 3531 y values correctly but wrong x axis time labels, like 25 seconds instead of 25 minutes.

[image]

timestamps are not completely regular and have ms decimals

```
0      2022-05-16 19:59:25.690
1      2022-05-16 19:59:25.890
2      2022-05-16 19:59:26.100
3      2022-05-16 19:59:26.320
4      2022-05-16 19:59:26.530
                 ...          
3526   2022-05-16 20:24:51.690
3527   2022-05-16 20:24:52.420
3528   2022-05-16 20:24:52.740
3529   2022-05-16 20:24:53.210
3530   2022-05-16 20:24:54.570

Name: time, Length: 3531, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`matplotlib.dates`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) to set ticks interval and format.
For example you could use:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval = 1))
```

in order to set a tick for each minute and

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

in order to change tick label format to *HOUR:MINUTE*.
Eventually, you could also use

```
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)
```

to rotate tick label by 90 degrees, in order to improve readibility.
You can change above parameters as you please in order to better plot your particoular data.

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


N = 3531
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = pd.date_range(start = '2022-05-16 19:59:25.69', end = '2022-05-16 20:24:54.570', periods = N)
df['Power'] = np.random.rand(N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df['time'], df['Power'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: this did the trick:  
`ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))`
thanks!!